# Failing to build project with project dependency

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created a small web application that relies on another shared project within my Visual Studio solution. Locally everything works; builds and runs on debugging. The small web application is using a mongodb and I am trying to incorporate my project to the docker-compose file as I want to append the solution with other project when my webapp is up and running.

When running the docker-compose file it does not seem to be able to resolve the webapp itself of the dependancy project (shared). The `Dockerfile` is created with Visual Studio and after all project dependencies are set up.

I think the problem is that the `docker-compose.yaml` file is in the solution folder (were it suppose to be) and `Dockerfile` is in a subfolder. Webapp is only step one. My next step would be to create a new project that have som code run every x minutes. This will be another project inside the solution, with its own `Dockerfile` and configured in the `docker-compose.yaml` file.

My project structure:

```
mywebsite
|
|-docker-compose.yaml
|
|-mywebsite.app
| |- Dockerfile
| |- mywebsite.app.csproj (ASP.NET web app)
|
|-mywebsite.shared
  |- mywebsite.shared.csproj (classlib)
```

I'm trying to run `docker-compose -d --build` from `MyWebsite` directory.

My docker-compose:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  appnetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
    networks:
      - appnetwork

  app:
    build: ./mywebsite.app/
    container_name: app

volumes:
  mongodb:
```

The generated Dockerfile of my app:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["mywebsite.app/mywebsite.app.csproj", "mywebsite.app/"]
COPY ["mywebsite.shared/mywebsite.shared.csproj", "mywebsite.shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "mywebsite.app/mywebsite.app.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/mywebsite.app"
RUN dotnet build "mywebsite.app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "mywebsite.app.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "mywebsite.app.dll"]
```

Running this by the docker-compose results in the error:

```
 => ERROR [build 3/8] COPY [mywebsite.app/mywebsite.app.csproj, mywebsite.app/]                                                  0.0s 
 => ERROR [build 4/8] COPY [mywebsite.shared/mywebsite.shared.csproj, mywebsite.shared/]                                                     0.0s 
------
 > [build 3/8] COPY [mywebsite.app/mywebsite.app.csproj, mywebsite.app/]:
------
------
 > [build 4/8] COPY [mywebsite.shared/mywebsite.shared.csproj, mywebsite.shared/]:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: "/mywebsite.app/mywebsite.app.csproj" not found: not found
```

I will add that running the `Dockerfile` from the solution folder works fine, but not project folder itself. So whats docker-compose messing up?

`docker build -t mywebsite.app -f mywebsite.app/Dockerfile .`

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work!

Move the generated Dockerfile to the solution folder and rename it from `Dockerfile` to `mywebsite.app.Dockerfile`.

You will also need to edit the `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: mywebsite.app.Dockerfile
    container_name: app
```